# What distribution function do I get if I square lognormal data?

Tags: probability-distributions, logarithms

I draw some values from a distribution that is lognormal. I then square each of the values. Which distribution function will now describe my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is incorrect.  While it is true that the square of a lognormal random variable is also lognormal, the mean and variance are not doubled.  If $X \sim \operatorname{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where the parameters are inherited from $Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ under the relationship $X = e^Y$, then clearly $$X^2 = (e^Y)^2 = e^{2Y}$$ hence $$X^2 \sim \operatorname{Lognormal}(2\mu, 4\sigma^2).$$  That is to say, the **lognormal parameters** of the squared random variable are $2\mu$ and $4\sigma^2$, but these are not the moments of the lognormal distribution any more than $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance of the lognormal random variable $X$.  Explicitly, recall

$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[e^Y] = M_Y(1) = e^{\mu(1) + \sigma^2 (1)^2/2} = e^{\mu + \sigma^2/2},$$ where $M_Y(t)$ is the moment-generating function of $Y$; hence $X^2$ has mean
$$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = e^{2\mu + 2\sigma^2}.$$  The variance of $X$ is
$$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = e^{2\mu + \sigma^2}(e^{\sigma^2} - 1),$$
hence the variance of $X^2$ is
$$\operatorname{Var}[X^2] = e^{4\mu + 4\sigma^2}(e^{4\sigma^2} - 1).$$

Consequently the relationship between the means and variances of $X$ and $X^2$ are

$$\frac{\operatorname{E}[X^2]}{\operatorname{E}[X]} = e^{\mu + 3\sigma^2/2}, \\
\frac{\operatorname{Var}[X^2]}{\operatorname{Var}[X]} = e^{2\mu + 3\sigma^2}(1 + e^{\sigma^2})(1 + e^{2\sigma^2}).$$

In summary, the square of a lognormal random variable is lognormal, but the mean and variance are nontrivially scaled; their lognormal parameters are multiplied by $2$ and $4$, respectively (or simply doubled if we parameterize by $\sigma$ instead of $\sigma^2$).

Comment: Please don't answer very low quality questions.

Answer (score 0):

Because the lognormal distribution can be represented by $X = e^Y$ where $Y$ is a normally distributed variable, the square of the lognormal is simply $X^2 = e^{2Y}$. In other words, squaring a lognormal doubles its mean and variance.

Edit: I am incorrect. Squaring a lognormal will return a lognormal distribution whose $\mu$ and $\sigma$ parameters are doubled, but this does not double the mean and variance of the lognormal itself.

Comment: Thank you. So does that mean that the PDF would be the same as for a lognormal function, but I just double the mean and the variance?

Comment: Inaccurate: $2Y\sim \mathcal{N}(2\mu,4\sigma^2)$

Comment: Please don't attempt to answer very low quality questions, "the Baker".